# Time series library in Java

Tags: math-software, time-series

I'm looking for a library to do some time series analysis in Java but I can't find anything suitable. I've found plenty of libraries such as Math3 of JSAT but there's much I can you for my problem. As an example, I'd like to compute standard deviation over time, moving average etc for a specific time series.

Comment: By math3, do you refer to [Apache Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/index.html)?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut yes. I should've been more clear on that

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.jsc.nildram.co.uk/), but it looks oldish, as well as [this](http://jsci.sourceforge.net/). [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) is more recent, but I don't know if it will fit your needs.